# gem Devise Sign Out not working on Heroku but working on development just fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I am having trouble getting my sign out button to work on heroku app.

Js Code

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require turbolinks
    //= require bootstrap-sprockets
    //= require popper
    //= require_tree .
```

This is my Routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users
       as :user do
      get "signin" => 'devise/sessions#new'
     delete "sign_out" => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
     get 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#new'
      end
      root'home#index'
       get 'about' => 'home#about'
       get'pricing' => 'home#pricing'
        get 'contact' => 'home#contact'
        get 'about'  =>  'home#about'
```

This is my Application.html.erb

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Home", root_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "About", about_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Pricing",pricing_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><%= link_to "Contact",contact_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <li class="nav-item pull-md-right"><%= link_to "Sign In",signin_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>
      <li class="nav-item pull-md-right"><%= link_to "Log out", signout_path, :method =>:delete, class: "nav-link" %></li>

      <li class="nav-item pull-md-right"><%= link_to "Sign Up",signup_path, class: "nav-link" %></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

So what am I doing wrong any help would be great.

Comment: Aside: your indentation in `routes.rb` is _wacky_. Consistent indentation really helps readability. I advise you to take more care with it (and / or use a text editor / IDE that takes care of this for you).

Comment: <%= link_to "Sign Out",destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>

Answer (score 0):

I believe your link is wrong, specifically the path, `destroy_user_session_path` should work.

```
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, :method =>:delete, class: "nav-link" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to call `signout_path` you have to add `as: :signout` something like this;

```
delete "sign_out" => 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :signout
```